# RequestFactory production logging/diagnostic context

Tags: gwt, logging, requestfactory

We have gone into production with a GWT/RequestFactory based app. All pretty good but debugging is tough as we currently don't always know the service methods being called.

What is best practice for making life easy for ourselves when we have problems in our logs?

We use MDC to have username, user agent in our logs but it doesn't look that easy to log RequestFactory service method.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you looking for GWT remote logging?

Comment: Nope. We have that already ta, with all the pain of deobfuscating stack traces. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ServiceLayerDecorator` and override its `invoke` method to add your log (or MDC key/value) here.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, for some reason I thought getProperty and setProperty also used that. Did start wondering about dumping the RequestFactory payload to the log and using some sort of tool to look at it, don't know it that exists somewhere already.

Comment: Set the `gwt.rpc.dumpPayload` system property? (https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.1/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/RequestFactoryServlet.java) Analyzing the dump would require using [RF messages](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.1/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/messages/) directly though.

Comment: Thanks. We have some hooks in that area already so could add to MDC (presumably cheap if you don't dump it). Looking at the errors I'm meant to be fixing a lot of them are before or after the service method call so capturing the RF payload early might be the best bet.

Comment: Might try and aim for replaying failed request on a dev machine with same code and data... Lot of head scratching at the stack traces at the moment.